# How to see which admin unblocked a user in Civi / Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I'm new to Civi / Drupal. In Drupal, there's the option to unblock users. Do you guys know how we would be able to check and see which admin unblocked any given user?
[image: unblock selected user]

This could be in the contact record, as an email notification to us, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

May be installing https://www.drupal.org/project/user_activity_log module would provide some details